# Salvar informação caso o usuário saia da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

A página em questão tem um formulário logo de cara, esse formulário tem só três campos, que são as informações básicas necessárias, após clicar no botão, os campos vão sumir e aparecerão novos campos com informações complementares.

O problema é seguinte, o cliente não quer que dois e-mails sejam mandados, o que ele quer é que:
 - Caso o cliente preencha o restante do formulário, o email vai com todas as informações.
 - Caso o cliente preencha o primeiro formulário e saia da página quando o segundo for aberto, só as informações do primeiro sejam enviadas.

Entendo que usando BD a solução é simples, mas estou buscando uma solução que rode apenas no cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o exemplo abaixo:

```
<body onunload="Funcao();">
```

Maiores detalhes nesse site: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `localStorage`, para armazenar alguns `objetos/variáveis` no navegador do cliente, esse `localStorage` **não expira** quando o navegador fecha.

[documentação do localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Exemplos para gravar:

```
localStorage.setItem("Nome", "Otavio Rocha");
localStorage.setItem("formPreenchido", meuObjetoFormulario);
localStorage.setItem("umaVariavelQualquer", minhaVariavelQualquer);
```

Para recuperar:

```
var nome = localStorage.getItem("Nome"); 
var obj = localStorage.getItem("formPreenchido"); 
var var1 = localStorage.getItem("umaVariavelQualquer");
```